# How to form this zend_db_select statement to compare timestamp

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-select

This is what i am trying to do.

```
 id ip        timestamp           userid
  9 127.0.0.1 2013-06-27 16:52:49 35
```

I would like to first query table to see if ip for the user is persisted. If so, he/she voted 2) Check timestamp of vote against current timestamp, if his voting time is way after 24 hours, then allow him to vote again. Ensure he can only vote once in 24 hours.

This is my current zend_db_select statement. Has some problems coming out with the logic

```
function checkIfCanLikeH($hlid,$ip){
    $canlike = false;
    $currenttime = time();
    $checkquery = $this->dbo->select()
       ->from("hl", array("num"=>"COUNT(*)"))
       ->where("hlid = ?", $hlid)
       ->where("ip = ?", $ip)
       ->where("timestamp < ".new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'));
    $this->dbo->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $checkrequest = $this->dbo->fetchRow($checkquery);
    if($checkrequest['num']!=0){
        $ip = true;
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

I am stucked at how do i compare the timestamp. I need retrieve the timestamp from table and check if the current time is smaller than value in table (added 24 hours).

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
->where("timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)");
```

This is the advantage of using MySQL's timestamp/datetime/date column types - you can use its inbuilt date and time functions. And I'm pretty sure you don't need `Zend_Db_Expr` here.

**Edit**: I'm not completely clear what you're asking, but I think the WHERE clause above does what you want, just the other way around. You could do this instead:

```
->where("DATE_ADD(timestamp, INTERVAL 1 DAY) < NOW()");
```

which is the same thing but written a different way. This means "where timestamp + 1 day is less than the current time".

If it helps, try running this query on your database:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(timestamp, INTERVAL 1 DAY), NOW() FROM hl
```

so you can see how the `DATE_ADD()` function in MySQL works.

Comment: hi tim! thanks for your reply. Would like to ask how do i get the timestamp value from my table column and add 1 day to it. I need to compare the current timestamp with the timestamp (in the table + 1 day). can i do it in one query?